# How to convert NFC tag in NDEF to non NDEF

Tags: c++, c, nfc, mifare, ndef

Is there a way to convert the NDEF formatted NFC tag to Raw format again i.e making it non-NDEF.

Thanks in advance

Comment: “NFC” and “NDEF” probably make sense in a context that is not indicated by the tags C, C++ you have chosen. To get people that can answer your question to read it, you may try to improve its tags.

Comment: What do you mean by non-NDEF? You want to access the data payload attachted to the NDEF record?

Comment: I understand that totally and I need to know exactly how can i Write in raw mode.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases this is possible. There are 4 kinds of standardized NFC tags, by the NFC Forum, that can contain NDEF, and (at least) 2 proprietary ones.

NFC Forum tags:

1. Type 1 Tag: You can remove all NDEF related data, but blocks of the memory could be locked (made R/O), this cannot be undone, AFAICT.
2. Type 2 Tag: Some essential bytes are stored in write-once memory. This cannot be undone. The blocks of the memory could be locked (made R/O), this cannot be undone.
3. Type 3 Tag: The formatting procedure is proprietary, so in general, this cannot be undone (it would require cooperation by the manufacturer Sony).
4. Type 4 Tag: This can be implemented as an applet on a smart card. If you have the developer tools for the card, you could potentially uninstall the applet. It could also be a card like NXP's DESFire (you can remove the files for NDEF storage in that case, if you have the required access control keys).

Proprietary NXP tags:

1. Type MIFARE Tag: Based on MIFARE Classic. All content can be removed (if you have the required access control keys).
2. Type ICODE Tag: Based on ICODE SLI family (ISO 15693 compliant). All content can be removed, but memory blocks could be locked (R/O), which cannot be undone.

If you have an Android NFC device, NXP TagWriter app has an option to fully erase some of these tags (choose Professional edition for the UI mode in the app's settings to access this functionality).

Comment: Thanks for the information.Is there any tool provided by NXP to un-format the NDEF tag? As my aim is to format the raw tag to NDEF and do the Read\Write functionality but since I dont have enough card to test thats the reason i need to make it non-ndef.

Comment: [NXP TagWriter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter), which I mentioned in my answer, is the only tool I am aware of.

Comment: Does this tool really makes it non NDEF, I mean if I clean the tag using this app as you mentioned and when i check it again will it come out to show as not being in NDEF format?

Answer (score 0):

NDEF is written in hex. You can use a hex to ASCII converter to decode most of it but I don't think it does all of it.